# Show the limit exists almost every where

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. Define
$$f(x)=\operatorname{dist}(x,E)=\inf\{|x-e| \ : \ e\in E\}. $$
I want to prove that for almost every $x\in E$ that 
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x+r)}{r}=0. $$

**What I've Tried:** This looks very much like the right derivative at $x$. Noting that if $x\in E$ then $f(x)=0$ and thus 
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x+r)-f(x)}{r}= \lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{f(x+r)}{r}. $$
But I really don't know how to proceed from here... If $x\in \operatorname{Int}(E)$ then the limit should exist, so it seems we only need to worry about points in $E-\operatorname{Int}(E)$.

Comment: I changed \underset{r\rightarrow0^+}{\lim} to \lim_{r\rightarrow0^+}.  That is standard and appears as $\displaystyle \lim_{r\rightarrow0^+}$ in a displayed setting and as $\lim_{r\rightarrow0^+} \vphantom{\dfrac 1 1}$ in an inline setting. Also notice the way \inf is used. That results in proper spacing in things like $3\inf S$ and behaves with respect to subscripts the same way \lim does. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |x-y|$, $f$ is of bounded variation. Hence, $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere. Now, since $f$ is nonnegative and $f=0$ on $E$, for each point $x\in E$, $f$ has a local minimum at $x$. Thus, at every point $x\in E$ at which $f$ is diffetentiable, $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: I am familiar with the result that if $f$ is of bounded variation on the closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ then it is differentiable almost everywhere on $(a,b)$. Does this extend to any measurable set?... So $f$ of bounded variation on $E$ implies $f$ is differentiable almost every where on $E$.

Comment: @MAM Fix $a<b$. Then, $f$ restricted on $[a,b]$ is of bounded variation. Hence, $f$ is differentiable a.e. on $[a,b]$. Since differentiation is a local property, this means that $f$ is differentiable a.e. on the whole real line.

Answer (score 2):

Try applying the [Lebesgue density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue's_density_theorem) . It states that for a Lebesgue measurable set $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, $\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{\mu(E\cap B_{r}(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))}=1$ for almost every point of $E$. The idea is that for small enough $r$ the point $x+r\in B_r(x)$ must get arbitrarily close to some point of $E$ inside $B_r(x)$ for the maximum "gap" between $x+r$ and the other points of $E$ in $B_r(x)$ can only be so large as the the ratio in question gets small. More explicitly:

For small enough $r$, we have that $\frac{\mu(E\cap B_{r}(x))}{\mu(B_r(x))}>1-\epsilon$. It must be the case that $f(x+r)<\mu(B_r(x))-\mu(E\cap B_r(x))$ (if you're having trouble seeing this draw a picture). Manipulating the first inequality, we see that $\mu(B_r(x))-\mu(E\cap B_r(x))<\epsilon\mu(B_r(x))=2r\epsilon$ so it follows that $f(x+r)<2r\epsilon$ for all $r$ sufficiently small.